# How to combine C# code with JavaScript code in onclick?

Tags: c#, javascript, onclick

I want to use C# code and JavaScript in the same `onclientclick` event.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbTest" runat="server" Text='<%#Text%>' 
    OnClientClick='<%#string.Format("passAccessory(\"{0}\");", Eval("Ref"))%>; window.close();' />
```

But it doesn't work. How to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What happens?

Comment: The content of linkbutton is not correct. I doesn't show the variable and close the window, but show the hard text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you reying to acheive? Do you wnat to call a javascript function which uses some of server side variables and close at the end.

```
function MyF()
{
    var myvar = '<%= myC#Var %>';
    ....do something

   window.close()

}


<asp:LinkButton ID="lbTest" runat="server"  OnClientClick='MyF()' />
```

Answer (score 0):

add an OnClientClick and OnClick events. The OnClientClick event will be executed first then the OnClick event.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbTest" runat="server" OnClientClick="test()" OnClick="lbTest_Click" />
```